# Image is not loaded in flutter application using Image.assets

Tags: image, flutter, user-interface, upload, flutter-layout

The app is show image is not loaded in the application.

[image: Output in cmd]

[image: Code]

[image: yaml file]

Comment: Can you show me your `pubspec.yaml` file ? and image location in `asset` folder also

Comment: have you register the `-assets/newlogo.jpeg` on your `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Yes I Was Added

Answer (score 1):

- Exit the application.
- Run `flutter clean`.
- Then start the application.

Comment: `flutter pub get` should also be executed before starting app.

Comment: Yes, Working, Thanks